# Second monitor is wavy

Tags: display

I have two monitors on my work system.

One of them gets refresh waves in it.  Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Graphics Controller lets you try increasing the refresh rate.  Depending on the monitor you may not be able to increase the rate.  Cheap monitors will often do that and sometime there is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

Any magnets or speakers close to that monitor?